# How to drop rows for those column elements which are list?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

[image]

In the above image, the last column ('Location') is a list. I need to drop those rows for the following conditions:

```
if first item in the list 'location' is greater than 60.0, those rows are not needed for me
```

if i use:

```
for i in range(len(output)):
    trip_df = output.drop(output[ output['location'][i][0] > 60].index)
```

Error is : KeywordError: True

I cannot simply put **output['location'][0]** since it would denote only the first row alone, how can i do this with or without the for loop?

P.S : Sorry for the image, I don't know how to put the values in a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` method to obtain the first item:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Location":[[61,50],[117,24],[3,5]],     #dummy data
                   "Values":[2,4,6]})

print (df[~df["Location"].str[0].gt(60)])

  Location  Values
2   [3, 5]       6
```